# React CSS animation triggers 2 times

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have 2 animations once first finish second have to start working, and its working greate, but when second animation come and finish his animation he retriggering one more time.

Here is a Full code

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import "../Hero.css"
import fog from "../../../photos/fog.jpg"
import ig from "../../../photos/iguana.jpg"
import moun from "../../../photos/mountains.jpg"
import moun2 from "../../../photos/mountains2.jpg"
import train from "../../../photos/train.jpg"
import Showcase from '../../../showcase/showcase.jsx';

function Hero1() {


  const sectionRef = useRef(null);
  const [showImages, SetshowImages] = useState(false);
  const [transictionEnd, SettransictionEnd] = useState(false);
  const [transictionEnd2, SettransictionEnd2] = useState(false);
  const [showImages2, SetshowImages2] = useState(false);


  const handleEndTranictionForGrid12imgs = () => {
    SettransictionEnd(true);
    SetshowImages(false);
    SetshowImages2(true);

  }
  const handleEndTranictionForGrid12imgs2 = () => {
    SetshowImages2(false);
    SettransictionEnd2(true);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleIns = (entries) => {
      const entry = entries[0];
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        SetshowImages(true);
      }
      else {
        SetshowImages(false);

      }
    }
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIns, {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: 0.5
    })
    if (sectionRef.current) {
      observer.observe(sectionRef.current);
    }
    return () => {
      if (sectionRef.current) {
        observer.unobserve(sectionRef.current);
      }
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div ref={sectionRef} className='Hero1' >
      <div className='Hero1_Title'> <div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', textAlign: 'center' }}><p>THIS IS</p></div><div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', textAlign: 'center' }}><p>ATLND</p></div></div>
      <div className='Hero1_img'>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={ig}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={moun}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={moun2}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={train}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={ig}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={moun}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={moun2}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={train}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        <div onTransitionEnd={handleEndTranictionForGrid12imgs} className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={ig}></img></div>
      </div>
    
      <div className='Hero1_img2' >
        <div className='Hero1_img2_upperdiv'>
          <div className={`${showImages2 ? "Hero1_videos_Show2_div1" : transictionEnd2 ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden_div1"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
          <div onTransitionEnd={handleEndTranictionForGrid12imgs2} className={`${showImages2 ? "Hero1_videos_Show2_div2" : transictionEnd2 ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden_div2"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        </div>

      </div>
     


    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero1;
```

This is first animation and working so good

```
      <div className='Hero1_Title'> <div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', textAlign: 'center' }}><p>THIS IS</p></div><div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', textAlign: 'center' }}><p>ATLND</p></div></div>
      <div className='Hero1_img'>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={ig}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={moun}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={moun2}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={train}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={ig}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={moun}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={moun2}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={train}></img></div>
        <div className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        <div onTransitionEnd={handleEndTranictionForGrid12imgs} className={`${showImages ? "Hero1_videos_Show" : transictionEnd ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden"}`}><img src={ig}></img></div>
      </div>
```

My second animation is this

```
      <div className='Hero1_img2' >
        <div className='Hero1_img2_upperdiv'>
          <div className={`${showImages2 ? "Hero1_videos_Show2_div1" : transictionEnd2 ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden_div1"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
          <div onTransitionEnd={handleEndTranictionForGrid12imgs2} className={`${showImages2 ? "Hero1_videos_Show2_div2" : transictionEnd2 ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden_div2"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        </div>

      </div>
     


    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero1;
```

Like i said, its trigger 2 times i cant understand why i tried to write state controls but when i make state controls, animations is not working.

```
   {showImages2 && (
      <div className='Hero1_img2' >
        <div className='Hero1_img2_upperdiv'>
          <div className={`${showImages2 ? "Hero1_videos_Show2_div1" : transictionEnd2 ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden_div1"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
          <div onTransitionEnd={handleEndTranictionForGrid12imgs2} className={`${showImages2 ? "Hero1_videos_Show2_div2" : transictionEnd2 ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden_div2"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    )}
```

```
      <div style={{display:showImages2 ? "grid":"none"}} className='Hero1_img2' >
        <div className='Hero1_img2_upperdiv'>
          <div className={`${showImages2 ? "Hero1_videos_Show2_div1" : transictionEnd2 ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden_div1"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
          <div onTransitionEnd={handleEndTranictionForGrid12imgs2} className={`${showImages2 ? "Hero1_videos_Show2_div2" : transictionEnd2 ? "Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2" : "Hero1_videos_Hidden_div2"}`}><img src={fog}></img></div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

These 2 either not working

Here is my css

For first animation

```
.Hero1_img{
    color: white;
    grid-area:1/1;
    place-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: 3fr 3fr 3fr 3fr;
}
.Hero1_videos_Hidden{
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: aqua;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-70px,-70px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    overflow: hidden;


}
.Hero1_videos_Show{
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: aqua;
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0px);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out ;

}
```

For second animation

```
.Hero1_img2_upperdiv{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;

}
.Hero1_img2{
    color: white;
    grid-area:1/1;
    place-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 6fr 6fr;
}
.Hero1_videos_Show2_div1{
    width: 550px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: aqua;
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    opacity: 1;
    grid-area:1/1;

    filter: blur(0px);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out ;
}
.Hero1_videos_Show2_div2{
    width: 550px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: aqua;
    transform: translate(40px,40px);
    grid-area:1/1;

    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0px);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out ;
}
.Hero1_videos_Hidden_div1{
    width: 550px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: aqua;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-70px,-70px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Hero1_videos_Hidden_div2{
    width: 550px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: aqua;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-70px,-70px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Hero1_videos_TransictionEnd2{
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: aqua;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease-out ;
    transform: translate(-70px,-70px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I was expecting animation gonna work perfect.